# How can I import a specific module with an ambiguous name?

Tags: python, django, module

This happens in Django context, but the question is not Django specific.

I'm trying to split my big `urls.py` into smaller and more manageable chunks (app includes, third-party modules, search, admin, development and so on). So instead of `urls.py`, I'm using `urls/` directory now, with `urls/__init__.py` containing code like this:

```
import admin
urlpatterns += admin.urlpatterns
```

Now I've got into trouble with third-party modules. For example, I'm overriding a bunch of URLs and views for `django-messages`, and so I've put all of it into `urls/messages.py`. It turns out, I can't import `django-messages`' views then, since

```
from messages.views import inbox
```

inside `urls/messages.py` tries to import from local directory first, finds a `messages` module, but can't import `messages.views` then, since `urls/messages/views.py` is obviously absent. I wouldn't like having to rename my modules to something like `urls.messages_urls`, but I haven't found a way to explicitely tell Python to import the "other" `messages.views`. Neither would I like to specify my imported views via strings, even though I can do that in Django.

How can I solve this situation cleanly?

Answer (score 2):

This is the wrong way to do it.

Django has a method for splitting urls.py into separate files, and that is to use [`include()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs). Keep the urls for each application in its own urls.py, and include them into the main one.

Comment: Yes. No. Both. My application-specific URLs are already in separate `urls.py` files and are getting included already. I would like to externalize things like "Development-specific URL patterns", "URL overrides for third-party modules" (e.g., I'm putting `django-navigation`'s breadcrumbs on `django-messages`' views), "Stuff I want to be able to deactivate with one commented line" (I know about `django-waffle`, just not implemented yet) and last but not least "devserver-specific redirects which are handled by Apache in production". 250 lines of `urls.py` is too much for me, I want to split it!

Answer (score 2):

For those who could not find it, I was hitting ambiguous import errors. For example, in a django project, let's say I have this tree :

- tax module

  - models module

    - **init**.py
    - tax.py
    - foo.py

In **init**.py, I want to import tax.models.tax.Tax.
So I write :

```
from tax.models.tax import Tax
```

But python does not find the correct import (it looks for models inside tax.models) and throws

```
ImportError: No module named models
```

You have indeed understood that it's all about relative imports. python first looks in the current module. If the first part of your import exists in the current module, it fails.
This behaviour has been fixed in Python 2.5 (and may have become default in Python 3.0), you just have to add :

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

before your absolute imports.
Have a look at [Python 2.5 introduces absolute imports](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports) for more thorough information.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
from django.contrib.messages.views import inbox
```

Untested, but I'd think the full import would work as expected.

Comment: Ah, I thought this had been rolled into Django, my mistake.  If you've included it somewhere in your project, perhaps apps.messages or projectname.messages for a more specific import?

Comment: You should probably use the full import everywhere in order to avoid confusion and make the code more legible.

Comment: `messages.view` is already full path. `django-messages` (http://code.google.com/p/django-messages/) and the `messages` framework included in Django are two different things (or at least they used to be). I'm using the former.

Comment: @kungphu: I'm trying to outsource as much code out of my project as I can, not include as much as I can :) `django-messages` is perfectly usable as a real third-party module, so I'd put it into my project only as last resort, right after renaming `urls.messages` to something else fails.